# Flutter: final field must be a one of the following

Tags: string, list, flutter

We have a widget class that has a final property of `this.type`. Currently this is a `String` and if the `String` matches one of the available types it returns the correct content via that widget’s builder.

Is there a way that instead of asking for a `String`, we ask for one of the available potential options.

Eg. Only `Block`, `Fixed` or `None` are acceptable strings. Can we make sure that the use of this `widget` can only accept those terms.

Comment: Add code for your widget class. These words don't make sense if we cannot see your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [enums](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types). First declare an enum using the `enum` keyword:

```
enum AcceptableOptions { Block, Fixed, None }
```

Then in your widget, use `AcceptableOptions` instead of `String`

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestWidget({
    required AcceptableOptions option,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

```
TestWidget(option:AcceptableOptions.Block)
```